# Allegro get current window size

Tags: c++, c, allegro, allegro5

In Allegro, I can set the Window to be resizeable by running

```
al_set_new_display_flags(ALLEGRO_RESIZABLE);
```

before

```
display = al_create_display(800, 600);
```

however, if I resize the window, how will I know how big the window is that I resize?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `al_get_window_constraints(ALLEGRO_DISPLAY *display,
   int *min_w, int *min_h, int *max_w, int *max_h)`.

[Source](https://www.mankier.com/3/al_get_window_constraints)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to respond dynamically as the window is resized, you should listen for [`ALLEGRO_EVENT_DISPLAY_RESIZE`](http://liballeg.org/a5docs/5.2.2/events.html#allegro_event_display_resize). Note that you'll have to register your display as a source for your event queue first:

```
al_register_event_source(event_queue, al_get_display_event_source(display));
```